# Writing a pandas dataframe to SQL using python

Tags: python, sql

I created a pandas dataframe that has 42 columns with multiple different data types. 
What is the easiest way to move this dataframe to SQL? Do I need to create the table in SQL and manually specify all data types and titles, or is there an easier way of managing this?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def move_to_sql(df, table):
    print("Start moving to SQL")
    engine = create_engine('connection_string')
    try:
        print("Loading db")
        df.to_sql(table, engine, if_exists = "replace", index = False)
    except Exception as error:
        print("Error loading data to table")
        print("Error message: {} ".format(error))
```

Comment: You need not to create a table in DB. when you connect it will create and stores the data into table.